# Proving the limit of $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ doesn't exist as $x$ tends to $0$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I want to do this by contradiction from the definition.

Assume for sake of a contradiction that the limit, $l$, exists, where $l$ is an element of the extended real line. Let $0$ be an accumulation point of of the domain. Notice that |$\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$| $\leq$ $1$ for all $x$ real numbers apart from $0$, so $l$ can't be ±$\infty$.

Let $\epsilon$ = $\frac{1}{2}$. If $0$ $<$ $x$ < $\delta$, when $ 0+2k\pi \leq x \leq \pi + 2k\pi$ then |$1-l$| < $\frac{1}{2}$.  If $-\delta$ < $x$ $< 0$, when $x$ < $0$, $ \frac{-\pi}{2} + 2k\pi \leq x < 0 + 2k\pi$, then |$-1-l$| < $\frac{1}{2}$.

We now have, $2$ = |$1-l+1+l$| $\leq$ |$1-l$| + |$1+l$| $=$ |$1-l$| + |$-1-l$| $<$ $\frac{1}{2}$ $+$ $\frac{1}{2}$ = $1$, which is a contradiction.

Therefore, the limit doesn't exist.

What mistakes have I made. I was considering using change of variable $y$ = $\frac{1}{x}$, so the question would be the limit of $y$ approaching $\infty$ of $\sin(y)$.

Made some edits above. Is it possible for me to prove this using this method with some minor changes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the limit existed, we would have that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin \frac{1}{a_n}$ would be the same for any sequence $a_n \to 0$. However,
$$
\lim \sin\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\pi n}} = \lim \sin (n \pi) = 0
$$

$$
\lim \sin\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} +2\pi n}} = \lim \sin (\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 n \pi) = 1.
$$

This means that in any neighbourhood of $x=0$ you can find values of $\sin \frac 1x$ as close as you wish to 0, and also to 1, which renders the definition of limit impossible to satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the definition of limits:
For all $l \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$,
there exists $\epsilon_0=|1-l|/2$, $\forall \delta > 0$, there exists $x_0= (\frac{\pi}{2}+k2\pi)^{-1} \in (0, \delta)$ for $|k| \in \mathbb{N}$ large enough, but $|\sin(\frac{1}{x_0})-l|= |\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}+k2\pi)-l| = |1-l| > \epsilon_0$.

For $l=1$, there exists $\epsilon_0=1/2$, $\forall \delta > 0$, there exists $x_0= (k2\pi)^{-1} \in (0, \delta)$ for $|k| \in \mathbb{N}$ large enough, but $|\sin(\frac{1}{x_0})-l|= |\sin (k2\pi)-l| = 1 > \epsilon_0$.

Comment: So you have proved the negation of the statement for convergence then, that is there exists an $\epsilon > 0$, for all $\delta$ such that there exists a value of x fo which the absolute value minus the limit is not smaller than $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is the negation of the statement for convergence.

Comment: I understand, but in the negation shouldn't you end up with $|1-l|$ ? Where does the $l$ go, it seems like you have assumed $l = 0$

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you! I just edit to better.

Comment: Ohh okay I think I understand how to do these types of problems now. I guess we chose $x$ to be $0.5\pi$ because that would give the largest value of $x$ possible - do we always have to do this or would it work if I used $\pi$ or $1.5\pi$ instead for example, changing my value of $\epsilon$ ? @Farmer

Comment: If you choose $\pi$ then you will choose $\epsilon = |l|/2$ instead of $|1-l|/2$.

Comment: Okay cool got you because I it is "there exists". Appreciate all the help : )

Comment: Say if I wanted to prove $cosn\pi\3$ diverged, that is different because it is a sequence of course, so I want to prove that it doesn't converge. Would I have to use 4 different cases because I can't see what other method I could do

Comment: I've edited it to be more concise. Similarly, for $u_n=\cos n\pi/3$: For all $l \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$, there exists $\epsilon_0 = |1-l|/2$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n_0=6n > n$ that $|u_{n_0}-l|=|1-l|>\epsilon_0$. For $l=1$, there exists $\epsilon_0 = 1/4$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n_0=6n +1 > n$ that $|u_{n_0}-1|= 1/2>\epsilon_0$.

Comment: That makes sense now. My final question is that how come you are choosing $6n > n$, because as $n$ continues to increase, wouldn’t the expression in the absolute value eventually become less than $\epsilon$. Same for the second case when considering $l=1$, like in that case what about for $12n$? In that case, $0$ > $0.25$ is false

Comment: Of course, for $l=1$, subsequence $\{u_{6n}\}$ converge to 1, show if you take $n_0=6n$, you don't get your hope. To do this type of exercise, you should be estimate $|u_n-l|$ before, and try to choose $n$ a skillful way. Try many examples you will experience.